# Creating and using device functors with Thrust

Tags: c++11, cuda, functor, thrust

I'm trying to create device functors using Thrust that will store a reference to a device data structure as their state. The functor would then get passed into `thrust::transform()` and friends. Problem is I'm getting errors about calling a host function from device code at the `return` statement of the functor:

```
// Compile with:
// nvcc --std=c++11 device_functor.cu -o device_functor

#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/complex.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

struct my_functor {
    my_functor(thrust::device_vector<unsigned char> &octets_) :
        octets(octets_) {};

    __device__
    unsigned char operator()(int idx) const {
        return octets[idx];
    }
private:
    thrust::device_vector<unsigned char> &octets;
};


int main() {
    thrust::device_vector<unsigned char> d_octets (4);

    my_functor foo(d_octets);

    d_octets[0] = 0x00;
    d_octets[1] = 0x01;
    d_octets[2] = 0x02;
    d_octets[3] = 0x03;

    std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << static_cast <int> (foo(2)) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

One of the end goals in doing this is accessing the bits in `octets` in various ways in the transformation, such as grabbing the fifth set of three bits, the  tenth set of four bits, etc. That's all easy once I can get the functor working.

Comment: This has no chance of ever working because of the device_vector within the  functor. That is the source of the error and there isn't a way to fix it.

Comment: why not just post an answer rather than modifying your question with "Edit 1:" which contains the answer?  Or if you prefer, I can mark this as a duplicate of other thrust questions asking about using thrust vectors directly in device code.

Comment: Will make this fix and mark the question answered. I didn't see it as a duplicate, as one question was asking about creating thrust vectors in device code vs. the other about using them in device code.

Answer (score 1):

Re-writing the functor thusly to address the comment by @talonmies appears to do the trick:

```
struct my_functor {
    my_functor(thrust::device_vector<unsigned char> &octets) :
        octet_ptr(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&octets[0])) {};

    __device__
    unsigned char operator()(int idx) const {
        return *(octet_ptr + idx);
    }

private:
    unsigned char *octet_ptr;
};
```